# Fill colors in Gnuplot

Tags: data-visualization, gnuplot

I am doing some histogram rowstacked plots using the gnuplot command

```
plot 'file.dat' using (100.*$2/$6) title column(2), for [i=3:5] '' using (100.*column(i)/column(6)) title column(i)
```

I want to change all the colors used for fill the bars in the histogram. For change the first box color, I simply add *lt rgb "color"* before the comma, but I don't know how to modify colors in the loop to make each box have a different color.

Modifying the line's style does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the answer by myself. Is pretty easy in fact if you know about the ternary operator in gnuplot.

The first thing you should do is create a function for set the color you want for each box. A valid function could be:

```
colorfunc(x) = x == 3 ? "#C17D11" : x == 4 ? "#73d216" : "#3465A4"
```

Then, in the for-loop part of the plot command you simply add *lt rgb colorfunc(i)*. The plot command should be

> plot 'file.dat' using (100.*$2/$6)
>   title column(2), for [i=3:5] '' using
>   (100.*column(i)/column(6)) title
>   column(i) lt rgb colorfunc(i)

and each color box will have the desired color.

I prefer to use HTML code in the color function, but you can use any of the valid ways to specify a color in gnuplot.